# Can Maven package two jar in one module , with the same files name but different chartset?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I have a project , just one module , but need to package two jar, with the different charset (just the `config.yml` file need two be differet, in the resources folder).

I have been try these way :

- use `maven-jar-plugin`, to add a classifier, it can package more than one jar file, but need to have one folder per jar in /target/classes . `maven-jar-plugin` can package two jar file , need different folder,like `**/server/**` and `**/client/**`, but I just need to change one file's chartset : `**/config.yml` with UTF-8 , and `**/config.yml` with UTF-16
- use `maven-resources-plugins`, try to change chartset, but the `<encoding>UTF-8</encoding>` seems not work..
- and I try to use `maven-resources-plugins`'s `copy-resources` , to copy the same .class file and the different `config.yml` (I create two folder in the `/src/main/`, for two chartsets, `/src/main/chartA/config.yml` and `/src/main/chartB/config.yml`) to two new folder (on compile phase, copy to `/target/ChartA` and `/target/ChartB`) but show `mark invaild`.. I don't know why.. and it seems following a zigzag course..
- at last I try the `<profiles>` tag, but seems can not package two profiles at the same time..

so , is that any way to replace one resource file or change the resources's chartset when compile/package and make two different jar package?

Comment: Unclear. What didn't work with the `maven-jar-plugin`? What does "need to have one document for one jar" mean?

Comment: `maven-jar-plugin` can package two jar file , need different document,like `**/server/**` and `**/client/**`, but I just need to change one file's chartset : `**/config.yml` with UTF-8 , and `**/config.yml` with UTF-16, just different form chartset..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

thanks every body, I use antrun at last :

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-antrun-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>1.8</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>install</phase>
            <configuration>
                <tasks>
                    <copy file="./src/main/resources/config.yml" todir="./target/ymls" encoding="UTF-8" outputencoding="UTF-16"/>
                    <copy file="./src/main/resources/plugin.yml" todir="./target/ymls" />
                    <move file="./target/${project.name}-${project.version}.jar" tofile="./target/${project.name}-UTF8-${project.version}.jar"/>
                    <jar destfile="./target/${project.name}-UTF16-${project.version}.jar">
                        <fileset dir="./pg/ymls"/>
                        <zipfileset includes="**/*.class" src="./pg/${project.name}-UTF8-${project.version}.jar"/>
                    </jar>
                </tasks>
            </configuration>
            <goals>
                <goal>run</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

this will help you change the chartset after package , and make two jar , needn't to copy one more files in resource, I set the default yml files UTF-8

Answer (score 0):

```
Try this :
    src/main/resources
       + config-utf8.yml
       + config-utf16.yml

<plugin>
    <artifactId>maven-jar-plugin</artifactId>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <id>default-jar</id>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/config-utf8.yml</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <include>**/config-utf16.yml</include>
                </excludes>
                <classifier>pack-8</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
        <execution>
            <id>special-jar</id>
            <phase>package</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>jar</goal>
            </goals>
            <configuration>
                <includes>
                    <include>**/config-utf16.yml</include>
                </includes>
                <excludes>
                    <include>**/config-utf8.yml</include>
                </excludes>
                <classifier>pack-16</classifier>
            </configuration>
        </execution>
    </executions>
</plugin>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!  but the config has to name "config.yml".. or the system can't read it (making plugin)..

Comment: I use maven-antrun-plugin at last , ant can change chartset and package more than one more jar file, so good for me